# Interplay between Riemann and Swinnerton-Dyer

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, riemann-hypothesis, l-functions

Hello everyone,

After reading RH ( Riemann's Hypothesis )  and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture, I asked myself why can't RH hold for $L$-Functions ( Hasse-Weil L-function ). In particular the [GRH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Riemann_hypothesis) imposes the location of finding zeroes of a $L$-function with $\chi$ character.

So in particular Swinnerton-Dyer's conjecture states that

> The underlying Mordell-Weil group of an elliptic curve has an infinite cardinality if there is a zero at $s=1$. i.e. $$E(\mathbb{Q})=\infty \iff L(E,1)=0.$$
>   $$E(\mathbb{Q})<\infty \iff L(E,1)\neq 1.$$ So can we predict that Hasse-Weil L-function of an elliptic-cruve satisfies the GRH. After normalizing can we put it this way :
>
> > There are infinitely many zeroes in the critical strip of Hasse-Weil L-function $L(E,s). $ i.e. Let $\mathfrak{K} $ be the number of zeroes of the Hasse-Weil L-function. Then $\mathfrak{K}=\infty \iff s=1+it$ ? . ( Assume that $E$ has infinitely many points, other wise $L(E,s)\neq0$.

I have some more set of questions concerning the significance of zeroes . They can be stated as

1. Are there any zeroes existing in the critical strip of $L(E,1+it)$ ? .
2. We know that $\rm{Rank(E(\mathbb{Q}))}= \rm{ord}_{s=1} L(E,s).$ So what about the significance of order of vanishing for other zeroes which are located at $s=1+it$ . Do they have some interesting relation with the properties of elliptic curves ? .

Are there any interesting results that are published in this direction so far ?

Thank you.

Comment: More generally, there are generalizations of RH for any automorhic  L-functions : see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Riemann_hypothesis


Comment: There are precise formulae to count the number of zeros on L(E,S) in the critical strip, up to a height T say. See: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71061/on-the-zeroes-of-hasse-weil-l-function/71062#71062 Moreover, it is generally believed that the nonreal zeros of L(E,s) are all simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to question 1, there are certainly zeroes on the critical strip. A great way you can investigate this is to go to the [L-Functions and Modular Forms Database](http://www.lmfdb.org/), where you can view plots of the associated Hardy Z-functions associated to the Hasse-Weil L-function of any elliptic curve over $\Bbb Q$ with conductor less than 240000.

For example you can go to [L-function of the elliptic curve 389a](http://www.lmfdb.org/L/EllipticCurve/Q/389.a/) and see that the Z-function on the bottom appears to have a zero of multiplicity 2 at 0. (It actually does because this elliptic curve has rank 2!) You also see many zeros of the Z-function between 0 and 30, I count 34. So yes, there certainly a lot of zeros of this Hasse-Weil L-function on the critical line.

I don't know a lot about zeros of $L$-functions so I don't know if there order of vanishing at the zeros away from the central point means anything. I would guess that the probability that a randomly chosen zero is anything other than a simple zero is $0$. (Analogous to the conjecture that a randomly chosen elliptic curve has probably $0$ of having rank $> 1$. Experts in Random Matrix Theory would know better than me, and hopefully they will appear soon.